# No BIOS to screen. What's happening here?

Tags: motherboard, bios, troubleshooting, updates, fan

I just built a new PC. I have a 650W PS, an ASUS Prime B350-PLUS MoBo mounting a Ryzen 5 1600 GHz, an ASUS GTX 1060 GP and two 4GB HYPERX ram banks (plus DD, SSD and a Wi-Fi card).

I press the powe button and the CU+Chassis+GPU fans start, but the GPU fans power down immediately. No Signal on screen (I have made sre that the monitor is on HDMI). The power LED is ON and it does not blink.

Trying to understand if I have a faulty GPU, I removed it, willing to use the HDMI port from the MoBo. Same behavior.

Tom's Hardware suggested removing RAM banks to see if PC-speaker signalled anything (it didn't).

I can't remeber exactly when it started happening, if after removing the RAM or after putting it back on place (or maybe after moving the HDMI cable to the MoBo plug), but now when I try booting the fans start, then the CPU fan slows down and MoBo leds start blinking slowly, every 5 seconds, fading to black and back to red. Fearing damage to the CPU, I kept the power button pressed to quit the PC. As soon as  started holding the botton down, the CPU fan went to full speed again.

I have tried switching the RAM banks, to no avail.

I have checked all PS>MoBo connectors and they are solidly in.

I think the problem might be that the Ryzen core is not recognized by the old BIOS but updating the BIOS with a slowing down CPU fan seems like a bad move: I can't reset the PC while I update the BIOS and if the fan fails, the core will die.

What's happening here? What should I do (apart from contacting ASUS's technical support)?

Comment: Was it working before or right after assembly the issues started? It seems you have fully built it into the case. I suggest you run it as a bare system outside of the case with just 1 RAM, PSU, Mobo,CPU & GPU. Nothing else and check if it boots. You can short the two pins for Power Switch on mobo using a screw driver to power it up.

Comment: Also it seems you have tried to connect your monitor to the HDMI port on Mobo. However AM4 boards have only provision of  Graphics out ports, they do not have any onboard graphics. CPUs like Ryzen 5 1600 do require discreet graphics card always. The HDMI out on mobo comes into picture only when you install APUs or Ryzen G series processors with onboard graphics. So with Ryzen 5 CPU you will never get any output on mobo's HDMI.

Comment: @pat2015 right assembled the issues started. Thanks for the info on the HDMI out on mobo.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, give a try outside of cabinet. Sometimes any short with standoff connectors or anywhere in cabinet might prevent PC from booting properly. Re-Seat the CPU again.